# How to split a file into multiple files based on a repeated string?

Tags: python

i have a file and a want to split the based on the string "async" into different files. The expected output is a little messy. I try to use a word as key ("async") to divide the file but the generated files have the first line of its function with the context of the below function. For example, the file is:

```
'use strict';
const shim = require('fabric-shim');
const util = require('util');

let Chaincode = class {
  async Init(stub) {
    let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
    console.info(ret);
    console.info('=========== Instantiated Marbles Chaincode ===========');
    return shim.success();
  }

  async Invoke(stub) {
    console.info('Transaction ID: ' + stub.getTxID());
    console.info(util.format('Args: %j', stub.getArgs()));

    let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
    console.info(ret);

    let method = this[ret.fcn];
    if (!method) {
      console.log('no function of name:' + ret.fcn + ' found');
      throw new Error('Received unknown function ' + ret.fcn + ' invocation');
    }
    try {
      let payload = await method(stub, ret.params, this);
      return shim.success(payload);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return shim.error(err);
    }
  }

  async initMarble(stub, args, thisClass) {
    if (args.length != 4) {
      throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 4');
    }
    // ==== Input sanitation ====
    console.info('--- start init marble ---')
    if (args[0].lenth <= 0) {
      throw new Error('1st argument must be a non-empty string');
    }
    if (args[1].lenth <= 0) {
      throw new Error('2nd argument must be a non-empty string');
    }
    if (args[2].lenth <= 0) {
      throw new Error('3rd argument must be a non-empty string');
    }
    if (args[3].lenth <= 0) {
      throw new Error('4th argument must be a non-empty string');
    }
    let marbleName = args[0];
    let color = args[1].toLowerCase();
    let owner = args[3].toLowerCase();
    let size = parseInt(args[2]);
    if (typeof size !== 'number') {
      throw new Error('3rd argument must be a numeric string');
    }

    let marbleState = await stub.getState(marbleName);
    if (marbleState.toString()) {
      throw new Error('This marble already exists: ' + marbleName);
    }

    // ==== Create marble object and marshal to JSON ====
    let marble = {};
    marble.docType = 'marble';
    marble.name = marbleName;
    marble.color = color;
    marble.size = size;
    marble.owner = owner;

    await stub.putState(marbleName, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(marble)));
    let indexName = 'color~name'
    let colorNameIndexKey = await stub.createCompositeKey(indexName, [marble.color, marble.name]);
    console.info(colorNameIndexKey);
    console.info('- end init marble');
  }
```

i tried this:

```
import re 
import os
filetype = '.js'
result = ''
count = 0
start = 0
name = 'functions'
matchedLine = ''
stringToMatch = 'async' 
with open ('myjson.js', 'r') as f:
    for x in f.read().split("\n"):
            if stringToMatch in x:
                if (start == 1):
                    with open (name + str(count) + '.js', 'w') as opf:
                        matchedLine = x
                        opf.write(matchedLine + '\n' + result)
                        opf.close()
                        result = ''
                        print (count)
                        count+= 1
                        matchedLine = ''
                else:
                    start = 1     
            else:
                if (result == ''): 
                    result = x         
                else:
                    result = result + '\n' + x
```

but the output is a little bit messy
function0.js:

```
  async Invoke(stub) {
'use strict';
const shim = require('fabric-shim');
const util = require('util');

let Chaincode = class {
    let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
    console.info(ret);
    console.info('=========== Instantiated Marbles Chaincode ===========');
    return shim.success();
  }
```

function1.js:

```
  async initMarble(stub, args, thisClass) {
    console.info('Transaction ID: ' + stub.getTxID());
    console.info(util.format('Args: %j', stub.getArgs()));

    let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
    console.info(ret);

    let method = this[ret.fcn];
    if (!method) {
      console.log('no function of name:' + ret.fcn + ' found');
      throw new Error('Received unknown function ' + ret.fcn + ' invocation');
    }
    try {
      let payload = await method(stub, ret.params, this);
      return shim.success(payload);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return shim.error(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this doesn't look like python code.

Comment: @TheMaker: The question is about Python code that works with JavaScript code as its source data.

Comment: @PM77-1 Ok I was just confirming. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be many ways to do this.  Here is one:

```
import re

class Writer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._num = 0
        self._fh = None

    def close(self):
        if self._fh:
            self._fh.close()

    def start_file(self):
        self.close()
        self._fh = open("file{}.js".format(self._num), "w")
        self._num += 1

    def write(self, data):
        if self._fh:
            self._fh.write(data)


writer = Writer()

with open('myjson.js') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match(' *async ', line):
            writer.start_file()
        writer.write(line)
    writer.close()
```

Comment: How does this code know when the async section is over to allow creation of a new file?

Comment: @RyanBarnes It doesn't know. The assumption in the question is that it is for use in cases where the next "async" will start the next file, so no sophisticated parsing is needed. This seems to be borne out by the example.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to separate all the sections that have async code into individual files, one method you might try would be to count the curly brackets for open, and then closed. To do this, you would set a variable that positively increments for every { and negatively for each } e.g (not optimized/pretty, just explaining).

```
brackets = 0
buffer = ""
found_async = False
for line_of_code in code:
  if "async" in line_of_code:
    if "{" in line_of_code:
        brackets += 1
    if "}" in line_of_code:
        brackets -= 1

    buffer += line_of_code
    if brackets == 0:
         write_buffer_to_file_here
         buffer = ""
```

As a concept, this will probably not work as is, but should give you an idea of what I'm trying to say.